# JSP's not rendering in CHROME but there are no errors either

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm using APACHE TOMCAT 8.x and Eclipse Kepler and for some reason, and it's been awhile, the JSP page is NOT rendering. That being said, we're using ANGULAR.JS and BOOTSTRAP.JS as well as jsMATCH for noCache.js.

So, I'm scratching my head, as I begin to wonder if it's "sometimer's" setting in, now, trying to figure out why my JSP presents a BLANK page, but, the CSS is working since the color is NOT white but what the background color defined in the CSS.

Here's a clue:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

Notice the SRC=??? Well, I've come onto a project where I've only been here a week.  Things are going very well. Just  I'm a wee bit stuck.

Any thoughts, please?  It's got to be "sometimer's" because I'm well versed with a lot of code.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the browser show when you View Page Source?

Comment: All the code in my page, no errors in the console log... just the BKGND color of the page... that's pretty much it.

Comment: Wait... you are using JSP _and_ GWT _and_ bootstrap.js (just to name a few)?  The `src` is correct for the GWT history iframe that is used by GWT for correct back button behaviour. It is created statically in the source HTML and should not be a problem at all, unless some CSS resized it. Why do you think JSP rendering (which should be independent of the browser) is the problem?

Comment: Oh, btw, the code above the iFrame is about 20 JS references and below is the closing BODY and HTML tags. It's a lean page... Just saw your comment... HIS.... so yes, we're using ALL of the above and then some... My first 'thought' was the JSP but I can see now it's probably something else.

Comment: My bet would be an incorrect GWT setup / build&run / development process. If the GWT code is not compiled correctly and thus the resulting .js is missing then the page will remain blank (except for output from other technologies like JSP or static HTML). If JSP would be incorrect: Show the JSP to be rendered and the actual output of that JSP part.